# in google play store there is no update options

Tags: android, android-update-app

There is a problem in App update in my application, When there is new version upload in Google play store and when i redirect to Google play store for version update at that time there is no option for version update, there is still two options displayed uninstall or open.I have develop below code for version update.

```
try {
 startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("market://details?id="+PACKAGE_NAME)));
}
catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="+PACKAGE_NAME)));
}
```

Comment: yes, actually i have downgrade version and i also redirect to play store when server gives me response as a there is new version available still there is only uninstall or open option displayed.

Comment: play store version code is 1.1 and my application version code is 1.0

Comment: play store version code=2 and version name=1.1   , My app version code=1 and name=1.0

Comment: What wrong i do any one suggest me